# Order By SQL request by time range period, then other criteria

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table, let's call it `posts`, which contains posts. The posts have `title`, `content`, `date` (as `timestamp`). They can be upvoted and hence have a variable number of upvotes assigned to them.

What i want is a SQL way to order post by `time range`, and then by `upvote`. So basically the SQL request must return :

- The posts from today (assumed that the time range is one day) ordered by upvotes desc, then the posts from yesterday ordered by upvotes desc, and etc...

Is it possible to do this in one request, and what is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: could you please share your SQL statment so far to see if you were close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple columns into your ORDER BY clause, as long as they are separated by commas. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT title, content, DATE(date) AS postDate, upvotes
FROM posts
ORDER BY postDate DESC, upvotes DESC;
```

This will put today's date first, and within that put the post with the maximum upvotes first.

The DATE() function there pulls the date part of a timestamp value, which is what I believe you want, so posts are put together by the date itself regardless of time.

Although, you said the post can have upvotes, but you didn't list it as one of your columns. My answer assumes upvotes is a column in the post table. If it is not, and you don't know how to get that value, let me know and I can try to help you.

Comment: Yaay ! Date is actually for extract date part of a datetime sql field. But you put me on the way. The solution is : `ORDER BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)), upvotes`. Actually the upvotes are a count on a JOIN but i have no problem with that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! You taught me something new too, I thought DATE() worked on timestamp as well.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL statement should do/be editable to what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
ORDER BY 
    date DESC,   // Favour the newest date
    upvote DESC      // Now get the one with most upvotes
```

By default, SQL will order them ascending, whereas in your case, you want them descending, hence the DESC is required.

Using a comma (`,`) between your column names within your ORDER BY statement means that the one listed first takes priority, then the next (etc...).

Comment: Actually, this order by timestamp, and upvote for those who have the same timestamp. It's not what i'm looking for, but thanks anyway.